# Updating notification text in Android after expanding the notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification which changes its text completely after being expanded.

For example, the normal non-expanded notification would say something like "Tap to do X" which would have a pending intent.

If the user expands the notification, the text would then change to say "Here are some actions you can do" with a few actions added to the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the notification builder like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);

builder.setContentTitle("Title!");
builder.setContentText("Tap to do x");
builder.setTicker("Ticker");
builder.setSmallIcon(drawable);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.addAction(icon, "Open App", resultPendingIntent)
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);     

//Content hen expanded
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText=new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigText.bigText("Here are some actions you can do");
bigText.setSummaryText("Summary line");
bigText.setBigContentTitle("expanded title");


builder.setStyle(bigText);

Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ParentActivity.class);

stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager)
        mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```